# Does browserify still have a purpose after es6

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify

Does browserify, webpack, and other still have a purpose now than we have the module import with es6?

Beside of the coffee/typescript conversion, I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does browserify still have a purpose after es6

**Of course it still has purpose.**

Browserify/webpack resolves requires/imports and packages your code into a bundled file (or files). ES6 (ES2015) doesn't do anything to change that need.

Until the browser gets a native support for resolving `require` or `import`, many people will still want to package their code. *Even then*, bundling is still useful because you can package your code into a single http request instead of one http request per `import`.

Maybe after all browsers support http2 and native `import`, *then* you can start ditching the bundlers ^_^

Comment: Modules (`import` and `export`) are part of ES2015, but this feature is currently not implemented in any browsers natively.
I think the OP is asking: "Do we need webpack/browserify once browsers support it?"

Comment: @PaoloMoretti interesting, thank you. I was aware of import/export but I didn't know browsers planned on supporting that directly. Good to know.